# Highlight hyperlinks using python docx

Tags: python, hyperlink, document, highlight, python-docx

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LBHT.jpg)

I am trying to highlight a hyperlink in word document using python docx library. But it is not recognising the hyperlinks. Can someone please help me with the code for this. I have used python docx and RT in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful if you can share your code directly in the post.

You can check out the release history for python-docx. The functionality for hyperlinks is described but not yet fully implemented. This could indicate that we can soon treat hyperlinks more like runs [python-docx hyperlink documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/text/hyperlink.html?)

Until then, you can add hyperlinks like this and highlight accordingly:

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document()
p = doc.add_paragraph("Hello World! ")

hyperlink = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement("w:hyperlink")
hyperlink.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn("w:anchor"), "my_section_id")

new_run = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement("w:r")
rpr = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement("w:rPr")

hl = docx.oxml.shared.OxmlElement("w:highlight")
hl.set(docx.oxml.shared.qn("w:val"), "green")
rpr.append(hl)

new_run.append(rpr)
new_run.text = "my visible link text"

hyperlink.append(new_run)
p._p.append(hyperlink)
doc.save("hyperlink.docx")
```

The example above should give you the text "Hello World! my visible link text" where the green text links to the section with the ID "my_section_id" like so:
[image: Screenshot of text in word]

Hopes this answers your question...

Answer (score 0):

A hyperlink that already exists in a document can be found with [`Paragraph.iter_inner_content()`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph.iter_inner_content) (added very recently).

This iterates the `Run` and `Hyperlink` objects in the paragraph.

A `Hyperlink` object itself contains runs. These are where the visible text of the hyperlink is found.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#hyperlink-objects

These runs inside the hyperlink control the character formatting of the hyperlink visible text so it sounds like you would want to add highlight to those runs.

```py
from docx.text.hyperlink import Hyperlink

for item in paragraph.iter_inner_content():
    if isinstance(item, Hyperlink):
        ... do highlighting on hyperlink.runs ...
```

A hyperlink will often contain only a single run but it can easily contain multiple, for example when the hyperlink text was edited between different editing ("File > Save") sessions. So you probably want to apply the desired formatting to all the runs of the hyperlink.